# How do I paint a child window with FillRect()?

Tags: c++, winapi, paint, gdi, win32gui

I have a main window which is created with the following styles
`WS_CAPTION | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU | WS_TABSTOP | WS_GROUP | WS_VISIBLE`
and with ex-stles
`WS_EX_ACCEPTFILES | WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT | WS_EX_LEFT | WS_EX_LTRREADING`.

This main window has a child window on it, which is an edit control created with styles
`WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | ES_READONLY`
and ex-style
`WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE`.

I am going to use this edit control as a progress-bar control. I don't want to use standard Wind32 progress-bar control (`PROGRESS_CLASS`), because I want to do a some custom painting on it (e.g.; dynamically changing fill color, displaying text on it, etc).

I can paint any region of the main window by the following code:

```
// hWnd: Handle of the main window  
case WM_PAINT:
    hDc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &Ps);
        Rect = AFunctionToGetCornerThePointsOfTheEditControl();
        Rect.right = Rect.left + 3 * (Rect.right - Rect.left) / 4; // Fill 3/4 (75%) of it
        Rect.left   -= 10; // Enlarge the paint region a little
        Rect.top    -= 10; // so that we can see it if it stays
        Rect.bottom += 10; // under the edit control.
        hBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(50,100,255));
        ret = FillRect(hDc, &Rect, hBrush); // ret = 1 always
        ler = GetLastError();               // ler = 0 
    EndPaint(hWnd, &Ps);
    break;
```

It looks like this:
[image: appearance of the painted window]

I changed this code a little to paint the child control instead:

```
// hWndEdit: Handle of the edit control
case WM_PAINT:
    hDc = BeginPaint(hWndEdit, &Ps);
        Rect = AFunctionToGetCornerThePointsOfTheEditControl();
        Rect.right = Rect.left + 3 * (Rect.right - Rect.left) / 4; // Fill 3/4 (75%) of it
        Rect.left   -= 10;
        Rect.top    -= 10;
        Rect.bottom += 10;
        hBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(50,100,255));
        ret = FillRect(hDc, &Rect, hBrush); // ret = 0 always
        ler = GetLastError();               // ler = 6 (ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE) 
    EndPaint(hWndEdit, &Ps);
    break;
```

This time it doesn't work. The main windows completely disappears as soon as I drag some part it out of the screen area, and it becomes totally unresponsive. Desktop icons under it are visible, but are not clickable.

So, what do I have to do in order to paint the child window (the edit control)?

Comment: The proper way to do custom painting is to subclass it.

Answer (score 1):

This article helped me a lot: [Subclassing Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773183%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

First, I create a separate message processing function for processing child messages.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MyClass::ChildWindowProc(  HWND        hWnd,
                                            UINT        uMsg,
                                            WPARAM      wParam,
                                            LPARAM      lParam,
                                            UINT_PTR    uIdSubclass,
                                            DWORD_PTR   dwRefData)
{
    static PAINTSTRUCT Ps;
    static RECT Rect;
    static HBRUSH hBrush1 = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(50,100,255));
    static HBRUSH hBrush2 = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255,100,50));
    HDC hDc;
    LRESULT lResult;
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_PAINT:
            switch (uIdSubclass)
            {
                case 1:
                    hDc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &Ps);
                        Rect.left   = 0;
                        Rect.right  = (LONG) (((double) ITEM2_WIDTH) * Status::GI()->Get_JobCurPercentage());
                        Rect.top    = 0;
                        Rect.bottom = ITEM_HEIGHT - 3;
                        FillRect(hDc, &Rect, hBrush1);
                    EndPaint(hWnd, &Ps);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    hDc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &Ps);
                        Rect.left   = 0;
                        Rect.right  = (LONG) (((double) ITEM2_WIDTH) * Status::GI()->Get_JobTotPercentage());
                        Rect.top    = 0;
                        Rect.bottom = ITEM_HEIGHT - 3;
                        FillRect(hDc, &Rect, hBrush2);
                    EndPaint(hWnd, &Ps);
                    break;
                default:
                    return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
            }
            break;
        case WM_NCDESTROY:
            //ReleaseDC(hWnd, hDc);
            return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
            break;
        default:
            return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Next, I bind this function to the controls:

```
SetWindowSubclass(  /*_In_  HWND            hWnd*/          ed_cur_Progress.hWnd,
                    /*_In_  SUBCLASSPROC    pfnSubclass*/   ChildWindowProc,
                    /*_In_  UINT_PTR        uIdSubclass*/   1,
                    /*_In_  DWORD_PTR       dwRefData*/     (DWORD_PTR) NULL);
SetWindowSubclass(  /*_In_  HWND            hWnd*/          ed_tot_Progress.hWnd,
                    /*_In_  SUBCLASSPROC    pfnSubclass*/   ChildWindowProc,
                    /*_In_  UINT_PTR        uIdSubclass*/   2,
                    /*_In_  DWORD_PTR       dwRefData*/     (DWORD_PTR) NULL);
```

And, that's all! The result is amazing.

[image: appearance]

Comment: The device context returned from `BeginPaint` should not be relased by calling `ReleaseDC`. Worse though is that you're passing an uninitialized `HDC` variable to `ReleaseDC` in your `WM_DESTROY` handler. Another note on cleanup: `WM_NCDESTROY` is the final message sent to a window. That's where you should put your cleanup code.

Comment: @Tim Thank your for the information; I will change my code according to it. How do I relase the device context then? Do I release it in the first place?

Comment: The resources associated with the device context returned from `BeginPaint` are released by the system when you call `EndPaint`. I understand that leaving a 'dangling' `HDC` looks wrong, but it isn't. For reference see [Drawing in the Client Area](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162487.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

WM_PAINT you are handling is main window's. you need to draw the editbox in its owner WM_PAINT message. I guess you get the error from "hDc = BeginPaint(hWndEdit, &Ps);", you may check it.